# Same Variable in different Functions. (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables, constants

Newbie here, I am currently writing a "game" in ex 36 of LearnPythonTheHardWay.

If I wanted to ask for the user's name in one function. How can I recall that persons name in all the other functions without asking for it again, or setting it = to the name again? From my understanding variables in a function don't affect other functions, but what if I want it to?

```
def room_1():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print "hi %s" % name

def room_7():
    print "Hi %s" % name
```

Comment: Are you familiar with objects?  That's how you'd usually go about storing state (player's name, location, etc).  You *could* use global variables, but you *shouldn't*.  Using globals is a generally bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, first would be to create a class and set an attribute called `playername`. Something like:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self,playername=None):
        if playername is None: self.playername = raw_input("What's your name? ")
        else: self.playername = playername
        # initialize any other variables here

    def run(self):
        # all your code goes here, and self.playername
        # is always your player's name.

game = Game()
game.run()
```

The other was is widely (and properly!) frowned upon. You could use a global

```
global name
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
```

Now so long as you don't overwrite `name` in any of your functions, they can call `name` and access it as if it were a local variable.

EDIT: It looks like you're trying to build a game that should implement a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) which is almost certainly beyond your ability to make right now. You can CERTAINLY do it without one, but the code will always have that "spaghetti" feel to it. `class Game` is the first step towards the FSM, but there's a long way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare it as global when asking for the name, so it is available in other functions:

```
def room_1():
    global name
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print "hi %s" % name

def room_7():
    print "Hi %s" % name
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you can define a variable outside of a function, then call it with the `global` keyword.

Normally you would use a class for this sort of thing, but you'll get there eventually :o)

```
name = ''

def room_1():
    global name
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print "hi %s" % name

def room_7():
    global name
    print "Hi %s" % name
```